# Как реализовать подстановку разных символов в имя функции через %?

Tags: python, функции

Есть массив:

```
mas = ['a','b','c'] # обязательно символьные элементы массива
```

и есть функции:

```
def is_a():
    return 'result: A' 
...
def is_c():
    return 'result: B'
```

Нужно реализовать вызовы нужных функций, что-то наподобие такого:

```
for i in xrange(1,3):
    print is_%s() % (mas[i])
```

Я понимаю, что `is_%s() % (mas[i])` - это  бред, но я написал это просто чтобы показать что нужно сделать.
Подскажите как..

Comment: Понимаю, что можна реализовать через:  
    
    def is_char(char):
        if char == 'a':
            return 'result A'
        ...

и вызывать через:  

    for i in xrange(1,3):
        print is_char(mas[i])

но этот как-то "в лоб", чуть не то..  
Надеюсь, можно хитрее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
for i in xrange(1, 3):
    print eval('is_%s()' % mas[i])
```

Но чую я, что вы что-то страшное делаете.
По нормальному, это делается так:

```
def is_a():
    return "Print A"

def is_b():
    return "Print B"

dispatcher = {"a": is_a, "b": is_b}
print dispatcher["a"]()
print dispatcher["b"]()
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать про Eval.  
На счет страшного - нет. Просто задумался, как такое реализуеться, а правильно запрос в гугле сформировать не смог.

Comment: Еще есть exec(), насколько я понимаю аналогична eval(). А также посмотри на execfile() - очень полезная штука. 
Однако при использовании данных функций нужно быть дважды осторожным.

Answer (score 3):

(Для полноты) Функции в Пайтоне — объекты первого класса, и хранятся в одном пространстве имен с переменными. Соответственно, `eval` тут не нужен — можно решить все чуть более «в лоб» — через `globals()` (или `locals()`, если мы где-то внутри замыкания, суть та же)

```
>>> def spam():
...     return "spam spam spam"
... 
>>> globals()['spam']()
'spam spam spam'
```

Но это некрасиво, un-pythonic, и, вообще, как правило — плохая практика.

Другой вариант — если функции в модуле, то можно через `getattr`:

```
>>> import random
>>> getattr(random, 'random')
<built-in method random of Random object at 0x13eeea0>
```

В принципе, так можно поступить и для текущего модуля (имя которого доступно через `__name__`), если получить модуль через `__import__()`:

```
>>> getattr(__import__(__name__), 'spam')
<function spam at 0x13448c0>
>>> getattr(__import__(__name__), 'spam')()
'spam spam spam'
```

Но это все чисто технически возможные решения, и в настоящем коде так делать не стоит. Предложенный вариант со структурой `dispatcher` — самый грамотный.